# How to wait first for the retrofit response before returning the boolean

Tags: android, multithreading, boolean, retrofit, fragmentpageradapter

always returning the wrong value, before the request has been finish. The validation will already return the value without waiting for the response. I'am using retrofit for request then i put it on listener.

Thankyou for the help, suggestion is much accepted!.

this is my code, i have validation for the screen when it's true it will goes to another screen.

```
@Override
public boolean isValid() {
    if (NetworkUtils.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        final AtomicBoolean pass = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        Thread simpleThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                new ReprintOnlineHelper(rType, receiptNoEditText.getText().toString(), issuedDate, etTotalAmtPaid.getText().toString(), new ReprintOnlineHelper.ReceiptNoSearchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onServiceResponse(List<ReceiptNumber> receiptNumbers) {
                Log.e("receiptNumbers", "" + receiptNumbers.get(0).getTPAYRECEIPTNO());

                if (receiptNumbers.isEmpty()) {
                    returnValue = "eReceipt Number not found!";
                    val = true;
                } else {
                    String pdates = null, ddates;
                    try {
                        if (!receiptNumbers.get(0).getTPAYISSUEDDATE().isEmpty()) {
                            Date periodFormat = df.parse(receiptNumbers.get(0).getTPAYISSUEDDATE());
                            pdates = sdf.format(periodFormat);
                        }

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("ddd", "" + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    String tinNo = receiptNumbers.get(0).getTPTIN();
                    if (tinNo.contains("-")) {
                        tinNo = receiptNumbers.get(0).getTPTIN().replace("-", "");
                    }

                    Log.e("JAC", "" + receiptNumbers.get(0).getTPAYRECEIPTNO() + "---" + AlfonzoUtils.formatDate(DateUtils.simpledateToMillis(pdates, DateUtils.DateFormat.SIMPLE_DATE_5_FORMAT)) + "---" + MoneyEditText.toDouble(receiptNumbers.get(0).getTOTALPAID()) + "--" + AlfonzoUtils.formatDate(issuedDate) + "--" + receiptNoEditText.getText().toString() + "--" + tinNo + "--"+revenueCollection.getTpTin().replace("-", ""));

                    if (receiptNumbers.get(0).getTPAYRECEIPTNO().equals(receiptNoEditText.getText().toString()) &&
                            AlfonzoUtils.formatDate(DateUtils.simpledateToMillis(pdates, DateUtils.DateFormat.SIMPLE_DATE_5_FORMAT)).contentEquals(AlfonzoUtils.formatDate(issuedDate))
                            && MoneyEditText.toDouble(receiptNumbers.get(0).getTOTALPAID()) == MoneyEditText2.toDouble(etTotalAmtPaid.getText().toString()) && tinNo.equals(revenueCollection.getTpTin().replace("-", ""))) {
                        pass.set(true);
                        returnValue = "success";
                        val = true;
                        showMessagePrompt(rType,returnValue);
                        return true;
                    } else if (!tinNo.equals(revenueCollection.getTpTin().replace("-", ""))) {
                        returnValue = "eReceipt Number was not issued to this TIN " + revenueCollection.getTpTin();
                        val = false;
                    } else if (!AlfonzoUtils.formatDate(DateUtils.simpledateToMillis(pdates, DateUtils.DateFormat.SIMPLE_DATE_5_FORMAT)).contentEquals(AlfonzoUtils.formatDate(issuedDate))) {
                        returnValue = "Issued date is not valid";
                        val = false;
                    } else if (MoneyEditText.toDouble(receiptNumbers.get(0).getTOTALPAID()) != MoneyEditText2.toDouble(etTotalAmtPaid.getText().toString())) {
                        returnValue = "Total amount paid is not valid";
                        val = false;
                    } else if (!receiptNumbers.get(0).getTPAYRECEIPTNO().equals(receiptNoEditText.getText().toString())) {
                        returnValue = "ReceiptNo is not valid";
                        val = false;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(int err) {

            }
        }).reprintReceiptNo();

            }
        };

        if (!receiptNoEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && issuedDate != 0 /*&& MoneyEditText2.toDouble(etTotalAmtPaid.getText().toString()) > 0*/) {
            try {
                simpleThread.start();
                simpleThread.join();
                pass.get();


                Log.e("pass", "" + pass + "-" + pass.get() + val);


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return pass.get();
        }


    }

    return false;
}
```

this is my request in retrofit:

```
   public void reprintReceiptNo() {
    JSONObject jO = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        jO.put("xReceipt", receiptTypeNo);
        jO.put("xType", receipttype);
        jsonArray.put(jO);
        result.put("dataArray", jsonArray);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("dataArray", "----- " + result.toString());

    ServiceInterface si = BaseRestClient.getClient();
    Observable<List<ReceiptNumber>> call = si.getreprintReceiptNumber(result.toString());
    call.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<ReceiptNumber>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<ReceiptNumber> receiptNumbers) {
                    Log.e("receiptNumbers", "" + receiptNumbers.toString());
                    onReceiptNoSearchListener.onServiceResponse(receiptNumbers);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible for the `isValid()` method to wait for the service reponse if you have code outside the Thread you've created.

The method will execute the Thread, but while that Thread is executing, the rest of the code will be read, meaning the `return pass.get();` or the `return false;` statments will be read, causing the the method to return before the server response.

The solution its to change the way this was done. You should check if you can call the server and then created your logic in the methods `onServiceResponse()` and `onErrorResponse()` based on how you want to proceed.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?